# Throttling app for testing native apps in iPad/iOS

Tags: ios, throttling

Is there any app for throttling network speed in iOS/iPad? I have already tried an app called 'charles proxy' but it didn't work for me. This is to test native apps under poor connectivity. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `Network Link Conditioner`.

For details you can refer to this [link](https://nshipster.com/network-link-conditioner/) or you can find a lot of other docs on web.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Network Link Conditioner directly on device.
To enable it, go to Settings > Developer > Network Link Conditioner

If you don't see Developer option in settings, do following:
Connect device to mac -> Launch Xcode -> Open Settings -> Developer